# Largest K-multiple free set out of a fully ordered set

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

i'm struggling conceptually with this problem, i don´t know how to approach it in a clever way (without a computer, or at least without a brilliant algorithm). Mathematicians defined a k-multiple set as a subset of integers where there is not a couple of numbers where one is equal to another in the set multiplied by k. If k = 2, then {1,3,4,5,7,9}, is a 2-multiple free set over [1 .. 10]. The counting labour, here is to find the length of the largest k-multiple set given k (multiplicity) , and n (max bound of the subset of integers).

I have find several relations but i can't figure it out how to get those formulas, i really want to understand the process. Is there any book that help me to sharp my skills at this kind of problems?

Comment: May I ask where you found this problem, I am writing a little booklet in combinatorics for people in the math olympiad of my town, and would like to add this one. Than you in advance.

Comment: I find this problem in the UVA site for ACM programming competitions, the problems there involves combinatorics, number theory and geometry by computer. I hope you find this useful. Let me know about your book, i'll be very interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a given k we partition $Z^+$ into two different sets:

$E=x|k^m\leq x\leq k^{m+1} $for even $m$

$O=x|k^m\leq x\leq k^{m+1} $for odd $m$

This divides it into odd and even layers, it is clear that if y is in an odd layer then ky is in an even layer. and viceversa.

The winning set will be one of $E\cap \{1,2\dots n\}$and $O\cap \{1,2\dots n\}.$

To prove this take a set not of that form, make a process that passes all of the elements on odd layers to even layers.

Comment: Thanks, can you recommend me resources on Combinatorics useful for this kind of problems?, thanks

Comment: This is [the bible](http://www.amazon.com/Concrete-Mathematics-Foundation-Computer-Science/dp/0201558025/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1392001916&sr=8-1&keywords=concrete+mathematics), especially since you are going for a programming competition. It contains a problem very similar to this one also.